# How to select entries WITHOUT matching dependents in same table

Tags: mysql

What I have is a table containing people. Some people are primary entries and others are secondary (partners, children etc)
The primary entries have a 'cls' of say 3 (where cls is a column name). The secondary entries have different cls, say 4. The secondary entries also have a 'primary' field linking them back to the unique ID of their primary person. (primary field is empty on primary people)

What I want to do is select all primary entries that do not have anyone linking back to them.

Here's where I got to, but it is obviously not right. I figure there is some other form of JOIN that I need?  (pp1 is referring to secondaries and pp2 is referring to primaries)

```
SELECT pp2.per_ID 
FROM person pp1 LEFT OUTER JOIN person pp2 ON pp1.primary = pp2.per_ID
WHERE pp1.cls = 4 AND pp2.cls =3
AND pp2.primary IS NULL;
```

.

```
TABLE person
COLUMN per_ID, cls, primary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.* FROM person as p
LEFT JOIN person AS s
ON p.`primary` = s.per_ID
WHERE s.per_ID IS NULL AND p.cls =3
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. The p. and s. are swapped in the third line but I get your meaning and I like the clearer idea of using s & p instead of pp1 & pp2.